# ICOM R8500-Transfer data and audio through e-line services

Tags: receiver, icom, radio-programming

I have tree icom R8500 radio receivers and i want to upgrade my services from serial to Ethernet. Although i have successfully managed to transfer data from the receivers to my pc (which happens to be almost 80km far), it does not happen the same with the audio. I used 2  RS232-to-Ethernet converters and in between i have implemented a wireless network. Anyone has an idea on how to also transfer the audio of the receiver? To be noted that in the current state i use pcm-30 to make it work.

Thanks in advance!